# printing the output three times

Tags: text-processing, printing

I have a file called File1 in which I have one word: `Frida`.

How can I print the output of `cat File1` three times in the same line?

It should show

```
Frida Frida Frida
```

Answer (score 0):

For example so:

```
x=$(cat File1)
echo $x $x $x
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` construct to get the content of `file1` desired number of times, and use `printf` to print in required format:

```
$ printf '%s %s %s\n' $(for((i=1;i<=3;i++)) do cat file1; done)
Frida Frida Frida
```

Or in `zsh`, you can leverage `repeat`:

```
% printf '%s %s %s\n' $(repeat 3 cat file1)
Frida Frida Frida
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `cat` is not necessary in this case:

```
paste -d' ' File1 File1 File1
```

`-d` specifies the delimiter, in this case a space character.

If you really want to use `cat` though:

```
cat File1 File1 File1 | paste -s -d' '
```

`-s` specifies to paste the input in serial.

If you are talking about n>>3, you're probably better off writing a script.